# How to trigger build using Job-DSL

Tags: git, bitbucket, jenkins-job-dsl

How to trigger build when push is done on BitBucket, using Job-DSL?

[image]

I think it is something like that, but with BitBucket, not GitHub...

```
    triggers{
        githubPush()
    }
```

I am also looking for a "pull" behavior, with Jenkins looking every *N* minutes if there is someting new on BitBucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    triggers{
        scm("*/5 * * * *")
    }
```

worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using DSL configure block as mentioned by @daspilker. I also had to look at the Jenkins jog config.xml to figure out how to code the DSL.  This code worked for me.

```
job{
    configure { project ->
        project / 'triggers' << 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitBucketTrigger'{
            spec ''
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Bitbucket pullrequest builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+pullrequest+builder+plugin) is currently not support by the Job DSL. Someone created a [feature request](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26488) some time ago, but AFAIK no one is working on it.

But you can use a DSL [configure block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to add configuration for any plugin.

Comment: I'm not interested in building when there is a pull request specifically.

Answer (score 0):

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.triggers.TriggerContext.bitbucketPush

```
job('example') {
    triggers {
        bitbucketPush()
    }
}
```